# Is it forbidden for a Hindu to participate in Islamic prayers or rituals?

Tags: india

I have seen many youtube videos and photos of Indian Muslims worshipping Hindu idols or participating in Hindu religious activities. However, I never saw the opposite.

[image]

Do Hindus in India participate in Islamic activities? E.g., do they occasionally go to mosques to say prayers, etc.?

If not, why? Is it forbidden for a Hindu to participate in Islamic prayers or rituals?

Comment: How will Hindu scriptures talk about this given Islam came only very recently in history? Direct references can't be found .. If possible we need to find indirect references to answer this query.

Comment: Among Hindu scriptures only Bhavishya Purana talks about other religions but only in a vague way.

Comment: The Vedas do not address other 'religions' or 'creeds' as there was no distinction at the time as to these modern differentiation. There is the Santana Dharma - the eternal Way. Do you think the Lord is so small and petty that it matters to Him how you address him or where? If you are praying with Muslims can you not be thinking of your own Ishta in those prayers??

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, You are not answering the question. Rather you are throwing more questions at me.

Comment: The Vedas teach that Brahman manifests Itself where there is 'Existence, Light, and Love'. Therefore nothing exists but Brahman. Are not Muslims a manifestation of Brahman? GIta 9.26 says "whoever offers Me a leaf, a flower, etc...that I accept the pious offering of the pure in heart." If your heart is pure in its prayer and offering what does it matter who is standing or sitting next to you or where you are?? Worry about your own internals, not the outside surroundings.

Comment: Your question is flawed in itself. There are more Hindus who participate in muslim rituals etc than muslims following Hindu rituals.  Though it's not permitted by Vedas and Smritis as mentioned by Pradip Ji in his answer.

Comment: @RishX, *There are more Hindus who participate in muslim rituals etc than muslims following Hindu rituals.* --- supply me references.

Comment: @user366312 I can tell from my experiences :) . Similar to how you are referencing from youtube videos and photos... which are not always authentic...anyways, my muslim friends don't even visit temples when we went on trip but most Hindu friends had no problem going to dargah.

Comment: @RishX, *Similar to how you are referencing from youtube videos and photos... which are not always authentic..* --- stop dillydallying. Please supply me with references.

Comment: @user366312 just few days back we had Sundar Kandam in our home. Normally we don't invite muslims(since it's against their faith according to some) but thanks to your question we did. Now one friend didn't show up and other two girls came just to meet but didn't come inside and didn't take prasadam as well.

Comment: @user366312 if my personal experiences are dillydallying than so is your question. I assume you are a muslim and somehow this question is blanketed by your personal bias about Hindus being intolerant. Which is hardly the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this may not be a healthy discourse as per the forum rules. Anyways, it is forbidden for Muslims to participate in other religions affairs as it violates their core principle of Islamic monotheism. Any individual doing something against it is doing in his/her independent capacity.

Likewise, the Islamic prayer or Salah is an act of submission or accepting the one Islamic God as only deity worth worship. For a pious hindu, it's a contradiction to his own believes from indic scriptures.

Although, Hindu scriptures don't explicitly forbids it as most of them predates Islam. It is understandable that doing a contradictory prayer is not a wise act and might be sinful as taking a false Auth.

Comment: *I think this may not be a healthy discourse as per the forum rules.* --- why?

Answer (score 2):

This is what is stated in Mahabharata.

> Vyasa says, '..The rejection of one's own creed, the practice of other
> people's creed, ......- these all have been pronounced by persons
> conversant with duties to be acts that no one should do.’

**Mahabharata Santi Parva Section XXXIV-XXXV**

Hindus don't always follow scriptural advice. A cousin (sister) showed me a photo of her visiting Ajmer Sharif Dargah. In fact Ajmer Sharif is popular among Hindus although this popularity has taken some hit after an Imam of the Darga supported the beheading of some Hindus.

Comment: Please provide who the translator is...not familiar with a Sanskrit word for 'creed'

Comment: Kishori Mohan Ganguli is the translator. You will find his translation in sacred-texts.com/hin

Comment: Excellent answer Pradip Ji. To the point as usual...    Yes it's sad that Hindus don't even know their own religion and go to non vedic religious places just for their material pleasures. On a side note even before this imam thing,ajmer dargah had a dark past when it comes to Hindu women.